# How to separate the elements of a matrix with comma in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I would like to separate each element in the matrix below with a comma.

```
1     2     3   
4     5     6   
7     8     9
```

Here's my attempt:

```
s= sprintf('%.17g,',matrix)
```

Ouput=`1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,`

Desired output:

```
1,     2,     3   
4,     5,     6   
7,     8,     9
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the formatting of the entire first line:

```
s = sprintf('%.17g, %.17g, %.17g\n',matrix.')
```

MATLAB keeps re-using the formatting string as long as there are elements left in `matrix`.

To generalize this process, use the following expression:

```
s = sprintf([strjoin(repmat({'%.17g'},1,size(matrix,2)), ',   ') '\n'], matrix.')
```

So there's a lot going on in this one line - let's unpack it from inside out:

```
repmat({'%.17g'},1,size(matrix,2))
```

This sub-expression takes a single cell array of size 1x1, containing the string `%.17g`, and duplicates it into a cell array with dimensions specified by the next two arguments.  We want to construct a cell array with a single row (hence the argument `1`) representing all the format specifiers (`%...`) we need.  Since we want one instance of `%.17g` for each column, we use `size(matrix,2)` as the last argument to `repmat`, since that returns the number of columns of the matrix.

As an example, if you have 5 columns, you get this:

```
>> repmat({'%.17g'},1,5)
ans = 
    '%.17g'    '%.17g'    '%.17g'    '%.17g'    '%.17g'
```

Next, since you want columns delimited by commas and spaces, you can use `strjoin()`:

```
>> strjoin(repmat({'%.17g'},1,5), ',   ')
ans =
%.17g,   %.17g,   %.17g,   %.17g,   %.17g
```

Note the use of a comma and several spaces as the second argument (the delimiting string) to `strjoin()`.  Adjust the number of spaces according to your display needs.  We need one more thing to be able to print a multi-line matrix - a carriage return.  To do this, we use the fact that two strings in square brackets `[]` are concatenated by MATLAB:

```
[strjoin(repmat({'%.17g'},1,size(matrix,2)), ',   ') '\n']
```

This produces the final formatting string that we need.  All that is left, is to add the `sprintf` and pass in the `matrix` argument.  As Rijul Sudhir pointed out, you do have to transpose your matrix because MATLAB will walk down a column to pair the matrix elements with the format specifiers.

EDIT: Stewie Griffin was correct about the transpose operation `(.')` - code has been corrected.

Comment: You need to transpose matrix. So instead of `matrix` use `matrix.'`

Comment: `s= sprintf('%.17g, %.17g, %.17g\n',matrix.')`

Comment: Thanks, my apologies...tested on a symmetric matrix.  :)

Comment: Why not `s = sprintf('%i, %i, %i\n',matrix')`? The output is identical as far as I can tell. (I'm not saying `%i` is better, I'm genuinely wondering why you use `.17g`.. The latter seems simpler)

Comment: Also note that it's recommended to always use `.'` when transposing, as `'` is the conjugate transpose. It doesn't really matter when working with real numbers, but if you're working with complex numbers one day you might get some strange results if you're used to using `'`.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for your suggestions, they were very helpful to me, however, is there a way to adjust the script to work for unknown number of columns, rather than just specifying three columns? I may somethings have more than 10 columns, which by your codes, I would have to specify `%.17g` 10 or more times.

Comment: @Boby you can simple `repmat` it: `repmat(['%.17g'],1,n)`, where `n` is the number of times you need that.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: `%i` prints scientific notation for floating point numbers, which I assume the OP is using because of the `.17`

Comment: @gariepy and others, many thanks for your suggestions, your solutions were really helpful.

Comment: @Boby: Welcome to StackOverflow!  If this solution works for you, please accept the answer as an indication to future readers of your question that this is a valid solution.

Comment: @gariepy, I'll need up to 15 reputation in order to accept an answer.

Comment: @Boby: Actually, you need 15 reputation to upvote, but accepting an answer is different than upvoting.  You should be able to accept an answer as a new user.